# Create Reduced Resolution Dataset (.rrd) file with modern software

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, image-pyramids

I need to create, very specifically, a set of [reduced resolution dataset (.rrd)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000025000000) pyramid files for a large set of TIFF imagery. I'm using ArcGIS 10.2, and have access to Global Mapper and QGIS. ArcGIS only creates .ovr pyramid files. I'm at a loss on how to do this with software that no longer supports [nor creates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000019000000) these files for most image formats.

Is there a way to create these files with my software? Does anyone know an easily accessible software that will do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create overviews in RRD format with gdaladdo http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html.

However, without being able to test with your program I can't say if they will for sure work with it. Test and report how it goes. There are two ways for creating the RRD overviews:

```
gdaladdo --config use_rrd yes image.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

This will create an .aux file which contains the overviews. If the sixe of the .aux file goes over 2 or h GB there will be two files: .aux and .rrd.

Another possibility is to run gdaladdo as

```
gdaladdo  --config use_rrd yes --config hfa_use_rrd yes image.tif 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

This will create always both .aux and .rrd files.

Info found from gdal-dev mailing list thread http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2008-August/017850.html

Comment: Yours is the better answer, so deleted mine. Only 8 mins in it. :-)

Comment: Brilliant. The latter snippet works for me. The first one creates the .aux file but not a .rrd file. The funny thing is, I can't say for sure if the .rrd will work either because I also have no way to test it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user30184 Actually, I'm having trouble generating .rrd files as a batch. It doesn't write .rrds or .aux: for %i IN (*.tif) do gdaladdo --config use_rrd yes --config -hfa_use_rrd yes %i 2 4 8 16 32 64

Comment: Windows. It worked on a single file, and appears to be working on each file now (shows processing), but no files are generated.

Comment: Perhaps some trouble with quotation. I seem to have for something similar `for %%f in (*.tif) do (
gdaladdo -ro --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR %%f 2 4 8 16 32 64
)`

Comment: welp. I had an extra hyphen: -hfa_use_rrd. working now.